# How to substract numbers in a list?

Tags: r, list

I have a list containing numbers that i want to subtract from eachother. for example, in coverage_1: 10 - 20, then 40 - 30 and so on until i reach the last element in coverage_1.
input:

```
$coverage_1
[[1]][[1]]
10
[[1]][[2]]
20

[[2]][[1]] 
40
[[2]][[2]]
30

...............................

[[45]][[1]] 
30
[[45]][[2]]
40

$coverage_2
[[1]][[1]]
30
[[1]][[2]]
40

[[2]][[1]] 
80
[[2]][[2]]
90

[[71]][[1]] 
50
[[71]][[2]]
40
```

In order to do this i made a vector containing the number of elements in coverage_1 -> `length <- c(1:45)` and a empty vector -> `result <- vector()` . In the for loop, i made a simple formula to substract [[1]][[1]] - [[1]][[2]], then [[2]][[1]] - [[2]][[2]] and so on until i reached element 45.

```
length <- c(1:45)
result <- vector()

for (i in length) {
  x = coverage_list$coverage_1[[i]][[1]]
  y = coverage_list$coverage_1[[i]][[2]]
  result[i] <- x - y
}
```

This is the result of the used code.

```
 896 1318 1105 1311  873 1033 1723 2886 4454 1091 2849 1211 2510 2490  720  745 1494 1139  912  628  351  725 2193 1073  838
[26] 1888  826 1279  779 2990 1716  534  540 3682 3222  508  648 2287 2289 1858 1828 1249  472  983  559   46   47   48   49   50
[51]   51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71   72   73   74   75
[76]   76   77   78   79   80   81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89   90   91   92   93   94   95   96   97
```

What I want to know is how to do this for the whole list? So not only for coverage_1 but also for coverage_2 and so on. I have tried it with a nested for loop, but it doesn't work.

Expected outcome:

```
$1
 896 1318 1105 1311  873 1033 1723 2886 4454 1091 2849 1211 2510 2490  720  745 1494 1139  912  628  351  725 2193 1073  838
[26] 1888  826 1279  779 2990 1716  534  540 3682 3222  508  648 2287 2289 1858 1828 1249  472  983  559   46   47   48   49   50
[51]   51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71   72   73   74   75
[76]   76   77   78   79   80   81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89   90   91   92   93   94   95   96   97

$ 2
other values and lengths 

$ 3
other values and lengths
```

reproducible dataset. I would like to substract snp = 1325 - snp = 7 (then for every element in the list). The expected result is a vector (showed earlier in the question).

```
coverage_list <- list(coverage_1 = list(list(c("a", "b", "c"), 
                                        list(window = 2, snp = 7, bp = 0), 
                                        list(window = 66, snp = 1325, bp = 0), 
                                        c("snp1", "snp2", "snp3")),
                                    list(list(c("a", "b", "c"), 
                                        list(window = 3, snp = 80, bp = 0), 
                                        list(window = 70, snp = 1400, bp = 0), 
                                        c("snp1", "snp2", "snp3")))),
                      coverage_2 = list(list(c("a", "b", "c"),
                                        list(window = 2, snp = 7, bp = 0 ),
                                        list(window = 45, snp = 903, bp = 0),
                                        c("snp1", "snp2", "snp3")),
                                    list(list(c("a", "b", "c"), 
                                          list(window = 2, snp = 50, bp = 0), 
                                          list(window = 30, snp = 1403, bp = 0), 
                                          c("snp1", "snp2", "snp3")))))
```

Comment: Can you share your data `coverage_list`, preferably using `dput`?

Comment: No, I cant. The list contains too much elements to share. The list doesn't only contain these numbers that I showed, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you share only a small representative sample of it?

Comment: dput(coverage_list$coverage_1[[1]][[1]])   ->     list(10)

Answer (score 0):

I've included a small reprex of your data here. I think the list structure is correct based on your original question.

```
coverage_list <- list(
  coverage_1 = list(list(10, 20),
                    list(40, 30)),
  coverage_2 = list(list(30, 40),
                    list(80, 90))
)
```

I've used the `purrr` package to iterate over the nested list structure.

```
library(purrr)

map(.x = coverage_list,
    .f = function(coverage) {
      map_dbl(coverage, 
          .f = function(sublist) {
            vector <- (unlist(sublist))
            vector[[2]] - vector[[1]]
          })
      
    })
```

Basically, we iterate over the highest level of the list (e.g. coverage_1, coverage_2, etc), then for each of these iterations we take the sum of the sub-list.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I will try to adjust it to my dataset.

Comment: Was the code itself incorrect, or did the reprex data not match your data structure?

Comment: The code itself worked on your example dataset, but not by using my dataset.

Comment: To help remove this question from the "unanswered" pile, can you either update your question with the correct example data or accpet the answer?

Comment: In my question there is a small subset of the entire dataset

Answer (score 0):

I took this example from `purrr::modify` documentation:
I also think the following code might work on a similar structure provided that all the named components be on the same level:

```
l1 <- list(
  obj1 = list(
    prop1 = list(param1 = 1:2, param2 = 3:4),
    prop2 = list(param1 = 5:6, param2 = 7:8)
  ),
  obj2 = list(
    prop1 = list(param1 = 9:10, param2 = 11:12),
    prop2 = list(param1 = 12:14, param2 = 15:17)
  )
)

library(purrr)
l1 %>% modify(c("prop2")) %>% modify_depth(1, ~ reduce(.x, `-`))

$obj1
[1] -2 -2

$obj2
[1] -3 -3 -3
```

First I plucked the element "prop2" on "obj1" and "obj2" and did a cross subtraction the way you had in mind between deeper elements of the same name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work for my dataset. I think its because there are too many other elements in my dataset. Do you know a code that works for the entire dataset that I have processed in my question?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Unless we have a reproducible example data, I guess every solution may be misleading.

Comment: I added the entire dataset in my question. It's the last code. If you have a solution, it would really save some valuable time for me.

Comment: And I added a reproducible dataset.

Comment: Ok then let me see what I can do.

Comment: I found a very similar example in the `modify` family functions in `purrr` package. I could even alter the example codes to do a subtraction the way you would like it to. However, your "window", "snp" and ... elements are on varying levels some on level 4 down and some on level 5 which makes it more complicated. If only you could alter the data structure so that these could be on the same level, there was a way to do something about it. I will post the similar example and my code so that you can see how I did it.

Comment: Thank your for your effort. The code doesn't work for the my dataset because of the levels, but I found another way of getting the result. I will put the code in my question.

Comment: My pleasure I will continue to think about it and thank you for being the reason I learned a whole lot of thing today. I will soon get to the bottom of it and if so will reach out to you with the result.